# How to fix the position of navigation bar when using using IQKeyboardManager?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, iqkeyboardmanager

I am using "IQKeyboardManager" library, when to hit the text field then keyboard appears and all view push to top. Also, the navigation bar shows on top. How to fix the position of navigation bar.

Comment: You can put all your content inside a `UIScrollView`, so library just scroll the scrollView and will not move whole `UIView`. This is the easiest way you can fix this issue. From [this issue](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager/issues/500#issuecomment-218425426)

Comment: if you are using constraints this can be easily done, based on the requirement either add iboutlet for height constraints and update the height based on keyboard height, or add the bottom constraints and update the bottom constraints, if you want your navigation bar to stay and other views to move up, add top constrains and set constant = - keyboard height. basically using constraints you can update your view based on keyboard. 
and you don't need third party lib to achieve keyboard show hide handling :-)

Comment: Please check the link in following answer and follow it 

It should resolve all your problem

Comment: Did someone resolved the issue, I tried to change my UIView to Scrollview too but it din't worked.

Answer (score 1):

After searching for the same thing on library Github page i came across following, I am sure this is exactly what you are looking for.

[Keep UINavigationBar at the top (Don't scroll with keyboard)](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager/wiki/Manual-Management#keep-uinavigationbar-at-the-top-dont-scroll-with-keyboard-below-v600)

Comment: I think some one removed it

Comment: But anyways i added new one for official wiki of the library

Comment: bro i tried but could not be able to resolve the issue